# Mock Laravel Model with Database query using Eloquent Builder

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I would like to mock the model `TemplateLibraryCategory` so that I don't have to hit the database on my unit test. Whenever I run the test I get the following:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Unit\Http\Filters\V2\Template\TemplateLibraryFilterTest::filter_is_applied_when_category_query_is_passed_with_value
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException: No query results for model [App\Models\Checklist\TemplateLibraryCategory].
```

Which gives me the impression that the model is not being mocked as it should be.

This is how I'm mocking the model `TemplateLibraryCategory`

```php
    /**
     * @test
     * @group filters
     * @group template-library
     * @group filter-template-library
     */
    public function filter_is_applied_when_category_query_is_passed_with_value()
    {
        $mock = Mockery::mock(TemplateLibraryCategory::class);
        $mockBuilder = Mockery::mock(Builder::class);
        $templateCategory = $this->createPartialMock(TemplateLibraryCategory::class, ['withSubcategories']);

        $mockBuilder->shouldReceive('firstOrFail')->once()->andReturn($templateCategory);
        $mock->shouldReceive('where')->once()->andReturn($mock);

        $this->request->expects($this->any())->method('query')->willReturn(['category' => 'test-slug']);
        $this->SUT = new TemplateFilter($this->request);
        $checklistQuery = TemplateLibraryTemplate::filter($this->SUT);
        $this->assertStringContainsString('`template_id` and `id` in', $checklistQuery->toSql());

    }
```

Then on my `TemplateFilter` I have the following:

```php
    public function category(string $slug): void
    {
        $category = TemplateLibraryCategory::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

        $this
            ->builder
            ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($category) {
                $categories = $category->withSubcategories()->pluck('id');

                $query->whereIn('id', $categories);
            });
    }
```

By now I would guess that `TemplateLibraryCategory` is being mocked and both the method `where` and `firstOrFail` is mocked as well. Why is the test hitting the database?

Comment: It is due to how Laravels orm is bound to a model, in my opinion it is a waste of time to mock laravel models, no one does it on a higher scale afaik. Usually there is two aproaches to deal with this, use sqlite as your test db and never hit a "correct" database which i prefer. Another aproach is to encapsulate your model logic in services or similar and then mock the service instead of the laravel models. I can help you achieve both if you want to go those routes :)

Comment: @mrhn thank you for the comment. After reading some comments in another threads I have decided to go with feature tests and use an sqlite database to perform the tests. I was able to setup with github actions as well which was my main focus. Now I'm only using unit testing for very specific cases and avoid its complexicity